# Python: words in a string get stripped in the output

Tags: python, string, split, output, newline

I'm writing a text adventure in Python 2.7 and now want to make nice-looking output. I already tried to make a GUI with Tkinter, but it didn't work, because the user's text input could not be decoded in Tk, and I need it for German Umlauts. So now I'm trying to get good output straight in the Python shell or the Jupyter notebook. The problem is, when I do a print statement, I get output like:

```
This is a text and just a little exa

mple to show the problem.
```

---

But of course I don't want to get words stripped, like 'example'. It should look like this:

```
This is a text and just a little

example to show the problem.
```

---

I tired to work with the width of a display and thought that it would be good to split the string after 80 characters, but with the condition that it should only be split at a whitespace and not in a word. I wanted to do something like this:

```
def output(string):
    for pos, char in enumerate(string):
        if pos <= 80 and pos >=70 and char == " ":
            templist = string.split(char)
            ...
```

Strings are immutable, so I think I have to convert it into a list, but then I don't know how to put the split-position of the string and the list together. Maybe I'm thinking too intricately.

**Is there a way to say: If the string is longer than 80 characters, split the string at the nearest whitespace to the 80th character?**

Comment: post the actual input string (longer than 80 chars) and expected result

Comment: I think there are python libraries for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [textwrap module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html).

For example, if you want 40 character line width:

```
import textwrap
a = '''This is a text and just a little example to show the problem.'''
print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap(a,40)))
##This is a text and just a little example
##to show the problem.
```

Comment: This is exactly, what I was looking for (more than than plenty hours of frustrating coding :D) Maybe I searched with incongruous keywords. Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the first 80 characters of a string and find the last occurrence of the space character, and then split your string there. You can use `rfind()` for this:

```
string = "This is a text and just a little example to show the problem"
lines = []
while string:
    index = string[:80].rfind(' ')
    if index == -1:
        index = 80
    lines.append(string[:index])
    string = string[index:].lstrip()
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to do it. I will try this way too. Thank you!

Comment: well I wrote this without knowing about the `textwrap` library. That is probably a better way to go

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/textwrap.html) module.

`text_wrap.fill(your_text, width=your_width)`

Comment: That is the module, what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate it.